# Android VIEW GONE equivalent in ios

Tags: ios, view, constraints, visibility, ios-autolayout

In Android if we try to assign **gone** to a view's visibility the space occupied by the view will be occupied by the views below.

If we assign **Invisible** to a view's visibility the space occupied by the view will be hidden and the space will still be there.

so how to do that in iOS ?

How to do this in iOS Autolayout ?

is it possible that we can change the constraint in such a way it mimics **gone** ?

I am confused , how to make it possible ?

ofcourse I can change the frame of view to frame of next view but I can't do this to all the below views... because it involves autolayout constraints too .

Help me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Perhaps you can try setting its height width to zero?

Comment: Yes, in certain situations, just set the height to zero.  The actual answer is there's no equivalent in iOS.  Note that at **development time** you can use the rater silly "Installed" button (google or look for it on storyboard).  That feature is precisely what you want, but there is *no* such actual UIKit runtime feature in iOS, no.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question, it's an excellent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change view high constraint to 0, this way other views which depends on this one should act like in Android linear layout

**Update 1**

From iOS 9.0 UIStackView is available which acts same as LinearLayout in android. To enable this you can select 2 or more views in Interface Builder and at the bottom you can click the stack view button:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand ... can you explain please ? like what option to choose in view or constraint and where to choose high consraint to 0

Comment: You can add a constraint for height to the view you need to hide, than bind that constraint to your viewController (control + drag) and when you want to make that view to disappear just sent the constant of that constraint to 0

Comment: @Appu if you doesn't want to show the view again you can remove from view, use the removeFromSuperview() method in the view you want to remove

Comment: but what will happen to constraints that has been assigned to the view .... basically i want to move the view in bottom to the place where the other view is ...and it should not break the UI constraint logic

Answer (score 1):

If your app target is above `ios 9.0` then you can use `UIStackView` to achieve your requirements. Please find the below links for the tutorial.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview  or

https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: unfortunately I have to support from iOS 6